# Can someone fix my code for a button to copy? (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: javascript, button, copy, clipboard

So I need help to fix this code about Copy to Clipboard button.

I'm new to coding, I copied this from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHg6jQajaMs and I copied all of the code manually. Can someone fix this code for me?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://youtube.local/assets/dcode.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://youtube.local/assets/favicon.ico">

<style>

</style>

<body>
    <h2 id="title">Copy to Clipboard - JavaScript - dcode</h2>
    <input id="myInp" type="text">
    <button id="btnCopy">Copy</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const myInp = document.getElementById("MyImp");
    const btnCopy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");
    btnCopy.onclick = function () {
        // Step 1 - Select the text
        myInp.select();
        // Step 2 - Copying the text
        document.execCommand("Copy");
    };
<`/script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some tiny mistakes in your code.

First you are trying to select input, but using the wrong name. Your input is named **myInp**, you're trying to select an element with id **MyImp**.

Fixing the line to `const myInp = document.getElementById("myInp");` solves the problem.

You also have a backtick in the closing `</script>`.

After fixing this it works. Here's the script part with changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const myInp = document.getElementById("myInp");
    const btnCopy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");
    btnCopy.onclick = function () {
        // Step 1 - Select the text
        myInp.select();
        // Step 2 - Copying the text
        document.execCommand("Copy");
    };
</script>
```

You can see the two versions side by side here https://www.diffchecker.com/ETENDYop